# Import data from .csv to mysql into two tables using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Data in tables have a relationship via id, e.g. stackoverflow question has its tags, author, time posted.
Trying to write a code that concatenates tag and author to quote and inserts it to mysql.
My quotes are stored in a table called Posts.
Tags and authors are in a table Terms.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N00w.png)

Comment: So what is your actual problem?

Comment: In the relationship table, my post has id=1 e.g. 
id=1 connected to id=3 (tag id)
id=1 connected to id=10 (author id)
id=1 connected to id=8 (time_posted id)

Comment: @AbdukahhorKurbonov Where is the data stored? If you have it in a .csv then importing to mysql is as simple as: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: 2 tables in the database. 1st stores quote 2nd tags and author. Whenever it imports quote it also should grab tags and author.
my quote has id=1 e.g. id=1 related to id=3 (tag id) id=1 related to id=10 (author id) id=1 related to id=8.

Comment: As I understand it: You want to create 3 tables (Posts, Tags, Authors) from a single csv input.
For each Tag you want to either: match it to the existing Tag id or if it does not exist add a new tag id -->
Do the Same for each Author as you add the row -->
Then add the new post to the Posts table with the IDs of the inserted Tag or Author

Comment: Not exactly. 2 tables in the database. 1st stores quote/post 2nd tags and author. Tags and author are in a table called WP_Terms. Posts/Quotes in WP_Posts.
Grab the post/quote from .csv stick its tag and author and import each to their dedicated tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your MYSQL Schema should be created with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Tags (
  `id` smallint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
  `name` longtext(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE Authors (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
  `name` varchar(100) UNIQUE,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE Posts (
  `id` tinyint unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
  `author_id` smallint NOT NULL ,
  `tag_id` smallint NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Authors (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `Posts` ADD FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES Tags (`id`);
```

[image: Database for storing posts with tag and author associations]
Your python code will look something like this

```python
import csv
import mysql
# Setup database in some way to connect, depends on how you have your database setup
db

with open('posts.csv', 'rb') as f: #Open the file
    c= csv.reader(f)
    for row in c: #Assume there is no header row and read row by row
        #Get the id of the tag
        db.execute(""" INSERT INTO Tags (`name`) VALUES (%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)""", (row[0]))
        tag_id = db.insert_id()

        #Try to insert the author and if it exists get the id
        db.execute(""" INSERT INTO Authors (`name`) VALUES (%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)""", (row[1]))
        author_id = db.insert_id()

        #Insert the row into the Posts table
        db.execute(""" INSERT INTO Posts (`tag_id`, `author_id`) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (tag_id, author_id))
```

This is untested but should give you a good idea of what to look for.

[This might be helpful for the SQL mechanic](https://web.archive.org/web/20150825044925/http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/)